# Who has bought the autocompletion for linqpad?

Tags: linq, linqpad

Who has bought the autcompletion feature for [Linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net/) ?
I know it's only $ 19 but I'd like to hear from you if it's worth it... Does it have any bugs? Does it really help in speeding up your linq queries development? Is there any limitations or any particular thing you might have found frustating?

Any thoughts are appreciated ....

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I just purchased the autocomplete feature in LINQPad, and so far, it has performed exactly as expected, looks and feels very much like Visual Studio (e.g. tab to autocomplete works exactly the same)

It should be noted that the autocomplete only works for use in C# modes, so VB and SQL modes don't benefit from the feature.

Additionally, when using the C# Statements mode, the autocomplete works for objects already declared (any time "`.`" is entered) and it also kicks in for type declarations (i.e. when using the `new` keyword), but autocompelte does not appear when starting certain statements (e.g. starting a `while` loop.

To be clear, I've been very pleased with the performance of LINQPad's autocomplete.  Remember, when in doubt, press Ctrl+Space!

Comment: Kit, this pushed me from downloading it, being impressed, and purchasing the 'full' version, all on the same day. +1

Comment: Glad I could help, I reach for LINQPad any time I just want to "try something out quick" in C# and don't have the time or patience to start up a new project and mess with capturing the data an pumping it out to console etc, etc...  Be sure to look through the example code and try out the .Dump() method.

Comment: Using LinqPad without the autocomplete would be very difficult.  I would like to know how to use it with "Dynamic query", without doing the obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Just bought the autocomplete version and highly recommend it...I'd like to echo Kit's remark re the .Dump() method....once you see it used a few times, it becomes very useful.

Answer (score 2):

I bought it to support the authors, not really because I needed the feature itself.